# What is the difference between these two priority queue wrappers?

Tags: c++, stl, implementation, priority-queue

I'm creating a thread-safe version of A* for a college project, and ran into this weird issue where these two implementations of a priority queue are producing different results. I have stared at this for a while, and I'm starting to neglect the actual project work. Can anyone spot the difference between these two implementations?

```
template<typename T, typename priority_t>
struct PriorityQueue 
{
  typedef pair<priority_t, T> PQElement;

  class Compare
  {
  public:
      bool operator() (PQElement e1, PQElement e2)
      {
          return e2.first < e1.first;
      }
  };

  priority_queue<PQElement, vector<PQElement>,
      Compare> elements;

  inline bool empty() const { return elements.empty(); }

  inline void put(T item, priority_t priority) {
      elements.emplace(priority, item);
  }

  inline T get() {
      T best_item = elements.top().second;
      elements.pop();
      return best_item;
  }
};
```

And the second implementation

```
  template<typename T, typename priorityT>
  struct PriorityQueue {
    typedef pair<priorityT, T> PQElement;
    vector<PQElement> elements;

    inline bool empty() const { return elements.empty(); }

    inline void put(T item, priorityT priority)
    {
        elements.push_back(PQElement(priority, item));
        std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), [&](PQElement e1, PQElement e2) { return e2.first < e1.first; });
    }

    inline T get() {
        PQElement bestItem = elements.back();
        elements.pop_back();
        return bestItem.second;
    }
};
```

Note that I am not interested in what goes on behind the scenes of these two implementations unless it is relevant to the change in output produced by the functions I am using to interface with them.

Comment: One uses `std::vector` and the other uses `std::priority_queue`...Note that you haven't mentioned what the issue is, so your question is as good as "Why isn't this code working?" which is definitely not what stackoverflow is for

Comment: I think your queues return items in the opposite order.  `priority_queue` returns the front item, while your second implementation returns the back one.  What sort of "different results" are you seeing?

Comment: I can confirm direction of the order is the same, see my answer for the reason I had these issues.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason is, `std::priority_queue` returns elements of the same priority in a different order vs `std::vector`. I realize this may have been a silly question after discovering the answer, but the order in which elements of the same priority were received affected the efficiency of my algorithm. Sorry for the clutter, I thought somebody might find this problem interesting.